# ¿Como hacer que datetime se pueda leer y añadir al base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

He investigado caleta y seguido muy bien con el SQL Procedure sin problemas para evitar las inyecciones SQL, he estado tratando por horas para entender, he leído que hay muchas diferencias sobre timestamp (de html) y el current_time del php. 
Espero haber escrito bien para que puedan comprender mi problema.
Adjunto los archivos.

**Tabla Perfil**

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.5.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 01-06-2017 a las 05:48:07
-- Versión del servidor: 10.1.21-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `webpractica`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `perfil`
--

CREATE TABLE `perfil` (
  `id_perfil` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Perfil` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fecha_Creacion` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `perfil`
--
ALTER TABLE `perfil`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_perfil`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `perfil`
--
ALTER TABLE `perfil`
  MODIFY `id_perfil` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

**anadirperfil.php**

```html
<?php
$msg = $id_perfil = $perfil = $fecha_actual = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
 $id_pefil = $_POST['id_perfil'];
 $perfil = $_POST['perfil'];
 $fecha_actual = $_POST['fecha'];

 if($id_perfil && $perfil && $fecha_actual) {

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "localhost", "webpractica");

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
  }

  $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO perfil (id_perfil, Perfil, Fecha_Creacion) VALUES ('$id_perfil', '$perfil', CURRENT_TIME())");
  if(!$query) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
  } else {
   $msg = "Los datos se insertaron correctamente";
  }
 }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

**anadir.php o anadir.html**

```html
<form method="POST" action="anadirperfil.php">
id_perfil: <input type= "text" name="id_perfil"><br>
Perfil: <input type="text" name= "perfil"><br>
Fecha_Creacion: <input type="datetime" name="fecha" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago'); echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()); ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Aceptar informacion">
</form>
```

Si preguntan por el ultimo archivo, que tiene extensión diferente, he tratado de revertir este formulario, para que la fecha_creacion pueda leerse con la hora actual. (en html se deja como echo, pero en php, se puede leerla con la fecha de hoy y el día actual)

Al tratar de rellenar la información, en la tabla no se muestra nada, sólo el número 1.
Imagino que debe ser el problema del datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según reviso el error que tienes es en el formulario.
Estos son los tipos de input que existen:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Sin embargo bastaría mantenerlo como:

```
type='text'
```

Y en el Value para que se muestre el valor con la fecha y hora sería así:

```
value = "<?php date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>"
```

El formulario final quedaría así:

```
<form method="POST" action="anadirperfil.php">
id_perfil: <input type= "text"          name="id_perfil"><br>
Perfil: <input type="text" name= "perfil"><br>
Fecha_Creacion: <input type="type" name="fecha" value ="<?php date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Aceptar informacion">
</form>
```

También en el archivo recoges fecha por post y no lo utilizas en esta línea del insert:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO perfil (id_perfil, Perfil, Fecha_Creacion) VALUES ('$id_perfil', '$perfil', CURRENT_TIME())");
```

Lo correcto sería utilizar la variable $fecha que estás colocando en el formulario quedaría así:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO perfil (id_perfil, Perfil, Fecha_Creacion) VALUES ('$id_perfil', '$perfil', '$fecha')");
```

Con esto ya podrías recibir los datos por post y guardarlos en la base de datos.

Saludos

Comment: Segun me fijé, lo unico es que se podría cambiar el tipo de la tabla por `Fecha_Creacion` datetime DEFAULT NULL a Date? y que el html se pueda permitir mantener el echo del date("Y-m-d H:i:s") no en formato html?

Comment: Parece que tenia otra problema, tuve que reditar el anadirperfil.php, habia problema del query, se arregló recién, pero quedando igual sin un problema la tabla y al llenar el formulario, aparece asi en el base de datos en la tabla perfil: 2017-06-01 00:00:00. es normal ponerlo asi con el datetime?

Comment: Es normal si no especificas la hora en la variable que recoges los datos te pone por defecto 00:00:00

Comment: Al final resolví todo lo del datetime, tenías razón en solo añadirle el input type = text, ya que al aplicar en php, con echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); aparece como para postear con la fecha correcta del día de hoy cada formulario.
En el caso del html, solo aparece echo. Al rellenarle el formulario en php, se aparece en base de datos al igual que el formulario correctamente: 2017-06-01 10:57:01 gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: De nada me alegro que se resolvio.

Answer (score 1):

En html5 el input para seleccionar una fecha es de tipo date :

```
 <input type="date" name="fecha" />
```

y para seleccionar la hora  el input es de tipo time:

```
<input type="time" name="hora" />
```

aunque no te recomiendo usar estos input puesto que en Firefox no se soportan estos input, en lugar de ello te recomiendo buscar una librería que te genere un datepicker.

Comment: Tiene razón, revisé el link del comentario de abajo por los form input types, lo malo, es que si uso firefox. Espero que en el upgrade del html, se debería añadir el caso del datetime para futuros formularios. Saludos!